# inherit only child MappedSuperclass but not the parent MappedSuperclass class

Tags: hibernate, multiple-inheritance

I have a base class B.

```
@MappedSuperclass class B{}

@MappedSuperclass class D1 extends B{} //class D1 is really big
@MappedSuperclass class D2 extends B{} //class D2 is really big
@MappedSuperclass class D3 extends B{} //class D3 is really big
......
@MappedSuperclass class D10 extends B{} //class D10 is really big
```

And i need NewD1,NewD2,NewD3 .. NewD10 , all extending D1..D10 minus B.

Now i need to create a new class 
class NewD extends D but not B{} //here i want to extend D minus B
Can someone suggest how can i approach this problem?

unfortunately @Mohannad suggestion will not work, as i am having around 10 classes inheriting B .

I have tried or considered the following.
- have class D and B seperate.
- now create NewD extends D extends B //but this wont compile as multiple inheritance is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible in Java. Do you have control over D & B?

If you do, my suggestion would be to invert the relationship. Make D the base class, then make B inherit from D, and then your NewD class could inherit from D but without having B.

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up using a work around as nothing is promising AFAIK for this.

I have created dummy columns (defined in @MappedSuperclass class B{}) in the database table corresponds to NewD1,NewD2,NewD2 .. NewD10 .

I prefered this since i thought having dummy columns in tables is better than having duplicating all code .